# Where does Java end and windows start? File seperator Question

Tags: java, windows, unix, path

I want to launch a Java jar by Runtime but Windows is making problems again.
I know this must have come up hundreds of times but I tried a few things (like String.replace("/","\")) and since I cannot debug on Windows this is taking quiet some time.
This works fine under Unix:

```
public boolean run(String args[], String workingDir, boolean output) throws 

    FileNotFoundException {
                if (args.length <= 0) {
                    System.err.println("No cmd provided");
                }
                if (workingDir == null) {
                    workingDir = "./";
                }
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);

                pb.directory(new File(workingDir));
                Process p;
                int exitValue = 0;
                try {
                    p = pb.start();
                    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                    String line;
                    p.waitFor();
                    if (output) {
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            setChanged();
                            notifyObservers(line);
                        }
                    }
                    exitValue = p.exitValue();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    return false;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (exitValue == 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException();
                }
            }
```

launched by:

```
public static void launchApp(String subPath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String[] args = String.format("java -jar -Xdock:name=AppName -Xdock:icon=%sicon.icns %AppName.jar", subPath, subPath).split(" ");
    ExecRuntime.run(args, null);
}
```

Comment: And what your question / problem is?

Comment: Maybe the java command is not in the %PATH% on that windows machine ? And at least log the info in those exceptions, they might tell you exactly what's wrong if something throws.

Comment: I get a FileNotFoundException

Comment: Right, so it probably cannot find the java executable, you'll need to figure out where it is and provide a full path to it.

Comment: Then why can I start App1.jar in the first place?

Comment: If App1.jar is your main program, how do you start it ? Perhaps java just registered .jar as a handled file extension and you just double click that jar to run it ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard java system properties when doing platform specific things in Java to ensure that your application is portable.  See [System Properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) for more information on some of the values available to your app.

Comment: Look out for `file.separator` there.

Comment: I am familiar with file.separator but this would make the code unreadable if I would replace it everywhere. I am checking the OS and then replacing the / with \\ if it is a windows system. But App1.jar just cannot find App2.jar. Does Windows not know paths like .\\App2.jar?

Comment: I usually just get the file separator once at the top of a method, or as a static final at the top of a class and use a variable in place of the call to get the system property value.

Comment: But Java uses Usix style paths in its api as long as I don't execute something from the Runtime?

Answer (score 0):

After taking the code appart, I found the 2 errors:
1. My OS method used String.replaceAll("/","\") and threw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException (don't know why) but String.replac() works fine
2. I was naiv enough to think that the VM would ignore unsupported parameters like -Xdock:name and -Xdock:icon but it does not, so I made a seperate exec String for Mac.
Thanks for your hints and help!